# how to compile jinja2 with python sphinx

Tags: python, jinja2

I am a new user of Jinja2.I am trying to use Jinja2 template engine with python sphinx. I want to add some loops and variables from jinja to create a  html file . My .rst file uses a sphinx template and I am just writing the below line in the file : 
    {{ a_variable }}

Where do I need to specify the value of this variable (ex.  a_variable="hello world") so that "hello world" is displayed in the html file as text.

Answer (score 0):

You specific the variable in your render command.

```
template = jinja2.Environment(loader=jinja2.FileSystemLoader(["./templates/WebPages"])).get_template("WebPage.html")            
return template.render(SomeVariable='something')
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: and where do I put this render command , do I need to create a new .py file for this or do I need to write it somewhere in sphinx files , sorry but I am new to python.

Comment: I'm unfamiliar with sphinx.  You shouldn't need to create a new .py file if you have one.  How do you handle page requests in sphinx?  Please show some code.

Comment: there is no code as such in sphinx, I write the text in text files and build the project using make and the text is rendered as body in html page... to enter specific values in the html we can specify those values in conf.py like this:  `.. |version| replace:: 1.1.0 `  now `|version|` is replaced by 1.1.0 everywhere in html file.